# Marge /wrap two image into one image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need the image mask / wrap to these uploaded images. Please refer this link. I need same as this. https://stocklogos.com/logo/supernatural

Comment: I don't get it, what exactly you're asking for. And what are your attempts? And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: When image is upload image is save with company logo

Comment: So you want to add your company's logo to an uploaded image. OK, what are your attempts? and what's going wrong?